# How to make associative array using PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

Here I want to make an associative array.

My code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
    $data[] = $row;
    print_r($row);
}
```

print_r($row);

```
Array
(
    [employeeTraveld] => 1
    [total_Trip] => 23
)
Array
(
    [employeeTraveld] => 2
    [total_Trip] => 9
)
Array
(
    [employeeTraveld] => 3
    [total_Trip] => 8
)
Array
(
    [employeeTraveld] => 4
    [total_Trip] => 7
)
```

Using this above array, I want to make my expected output like:

`employeeTraveld` is `1` means I have to change the key value like `SingleemployeeTraveld` and value is `23` **(total_Trip)**

---

`employeeTraveld` is `2` means I have to change the key value like `TwoemployeeTraveld` and value is `9` **(total_Trip)**

---

`employeeTraveld` is `3` means I have to change the key value like `ThreeemployeeTraveld` and value is `8` **(total_Trip)**

---

`employeeTraveld` is `4` means I have to change the key value like `FouremployeeTraveld` and value is `7` **(total_Trip)**

Finally my expected result should come like this:

```
Array
(
    [SingleemployeeTraveld] => 23
    [TwoemployeeTraveld] => 9
    [ThreeemployeeTraveld] => 8
    [FouremployeeTraveld] => 7
)
```

My Updated Code

```
include 'dbconfig.php';
require('Numbers/Words.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$sql = "SELECT EmpId as employeeTraveld, Count(tripId) AS total_Trip
  FROM
  (
  SELECT COUNT(empID) AS empID, tm.tripID
  FROM trip_member as tm
  INNER JOIN trip_details as td
  ON tm.tripId = td.tripId
  WHERE tripDate BETWEEN '$today' AND '$today'
  GROUP BY 
  tripid
  ) AS trip_member
  GROUP BY
  EMPID
  ORDER BY
  EMPID";
$mysql = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
    $newArray = new array();

    foreach($row as $key=>$value){
         $numberToWord = new Numbers_Words();
         $newkeyWord = ucfirst($numberToWords->toWords($value["employeeTraveld"]));
         $newkey = $newkeyWord.$value["employeeTraveld"];
         $newArray[$newkey] = $value["total_Trip"];
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Quote formatting in questions is meant to identify quoted text like from a document/reference/resource.  It is not mean to be used a highlighter.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions.  Modernize your applications with `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: I wonder why you aren't using `One` where you are using `Single`.  Do you know if there is an upper limit to how many number-to-English translations you will need to do?  Might you actually need to convert, say, `216` to `TwoHundredSixteen`?  If your project will not get out-of-hand with the number-to-English assignments, you can hardcode a lookup array to avoid downloading a package.

Comment: @Kani are you going to respond to my request for clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert number into words - plz check https://www.phptpoint.com/convert-number-into-words-in-php/ with the help of using this function, I tried to figure it out:

```
function numberTowords($num) {
    $ones = array(
        1 => "one",
        2 => "two",
        3 => "three",
        4 => "four",
        5 => "five",
        6 => "six",
        7 => "seven",
        8 => "eight",
        9 => "nine",
        10 => "ten",
        11 => "eleven",
        12 => "twelve",
        13 => "thirteen",
        14 => "fourteen",
        15 => "fifteen",
        16 => "sixteen",
        17 => "seventeen",
        18 => "eighteen",
        19 => "nineteen"
    );
    $tens = array(
        1 => "ten",
        2 => "twenty",
        3 => "thirty",
        4 => "forty",
        5 => "fifty",
        6 => "sixty",
        7 => "seventy",
        8 => "eighty",
        9 => "ninety"
    );
    $hundreds = array(
        "hundred",
        "thousand",
        "million",
        "billion",
        "trillion",
        "quadrillion"
    ); //limit t quadrillion 
    $num = number_format($num, 2, ".", ",");
    $num_arr = explode(".", $num);
    $wholenum = $num_arr[0];
    $decnum = $num_arr[1];
    $whole_arr = array_reverse(explode(",", $wholenum));
    krsort($whole_arr);
    $rettxt = "";
    foreach ($whole_arr as $key => $i) {
        if ($i < 20) {
            $rettxt .= $ones[$i];
        } elseif ($i < 100) {
            $rettxt .= $tens[substr($i, 0, 1)];
            $rettxt .= "" . $ones[substr($i, 1, 1)];
        } else {
            $rettxt .= $ones[substr($i, 0, 1)] . "" . $hundreds[0];
            $rettxt .= "" . $tens[substr($i, 1, 1)];
            $rettxt .= "" . $ones[substr($i, 2, 1)];
        }
        if ($key > 0) {
            $rettxt .= "" . $hundreds[$key] . "";
        }
    }
    if ($decnum > 0) {
        $rettxt .= "and";
        if ($decnum < 20) {
            $rettxt .= $ones[$decnum];
        } elseif ($decnum < 100) {
            $rettxt .= $tens[substr($decnum, 0, 1)];
            $rettxt .= "" . $ones[substr($decnum, 1, 1)];
        }
    }
    return $rettxt;
}

$arr = array(
    array(
        'employeeTraveld' => 1,
        'total_Trip' => 23
    ),
    array(
        'employeeTraveld' => 2,
        'total_Trip' => 9
    ),
    array(
        'employeeTraveld' => 3,
        'total_Trip' => 8
    ),
    array(
        'employeeTraveld' => 4,
        'total_Trip' => 7
    ),
);
foreach ($arr as $subArr) {
    $numText = numberTowords($subArr['employeeTraveld']);
    $newKey = ucfirst($numText) . 'employeeTraveld';
    $newArray[$newKey] = $subArr['total_Trip'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/976348)

**Update**

you can write these lines after `foreach`:

```
if(!empty($newArray)){
    $data['status'] = 'success';
    $data['data'] = array($newArray);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Although this is probably the best answer on the page so far, this doesn't generate the desired `Single` string.

Comment: `$ones = array(
        1 => "one",...)` can update "single" in place of "one".

Comment: But then that will have a knock-on effect with larger numbers generated dynamically  ...`ninety-single`

Comment: thats why I used "one", this is also your question to @kani in comment, I think he can explain it better.

Comment: @Bhaskar Jain  I need output like this how can i get? **{
       "status": "success",
       "data": [{
         "SingleemployeeTraveld": "10",
         "TwoemployeeTraveld": "7",
         "ThreeemployeeTraveld": "4",
         "FouremployeeTraveld": "4",
       }]
        }**

Comment: @ Bhaskar Jain,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```php
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $array2){

    if($array2['employeeTraveld'] == 1){
        $newarray['SingleemployeeTraveld'][] =  $array2['total_Trip'];
    }
    if($array2['employeeTraveld'] == 2){
        $newarray['TwoemployeeTraveld'][] =  $array2['total_Trip'];
    }
    if($array2['employeeTraveld'] == 3){
        $newarray['ThreeemployeeTraveld'][] =  $array2['total_Trip'];
    }
    if($array2['employeeTraveld'] == 4){
        $newarray['FouremployeeTraveld'][] =  $array2['total_Trip'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($newarray);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future researchers.  Please improve your post with the intent to educate.

Answer (score 0):

```
require('Numbers/Words.php');

$newArray = new array();
foreach($row as $key=>$value){
 $numberToWord = new Numbers_Words();
 $newkeyWord = ucfirst($numberToWords->toWords($value["employeeTraveld"]));
 $newkey = $newkeyWord.$value["employeeTraveld"];
 $newArray[$newkey] = $value["total_Trip"];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

You can use this script. First loop through the array. You have a numeric values so you need to get the text from that. I,e 1 to One, 2 to Two, etc.

For this purpose we have use `$numberToWord = new Numbers_Words();` and then  `$newkeyWord = ucfirst($numberToWords->toWords($value["employeeTraveld"]));` here toWords return one if the number is 1, two if the string is 2 and so on. We have used ucfirst to convert first letter into capital. Finally when we have our key ready i.e OneemployeeTraveld, TwoemployeeTraveld, etc, we have added respective `total_Trip` to that key in newArray. You will get the expected output in newArray.

Here is a documentation link for `Numbers_Words()`
You need to use this package for that.Include this in your file.

[Number_Words](http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words)

[Ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

Comment: I tried like this but nothing is displaying **$mysql = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
  $newArray = new array();
  foreach($row as $key=>$value){
   $numberToWord = new Numbers_Words();
   $newkeyWord = ucfirst($numberToWords->toWords($value["employeeTraveld"]));
   $newkey = $newkeyWord.$value["employeeTraveld"];
   $newArray[$newkey] = $value["total_Trip"];
  }
  
  
 }
 print_r($newArray);**

Comment: I want to download any package and i have to include in my files ?

Comment: Download pear package in your pc. Move Number folder in your project folder.Include words.php in your file like require('Numbers/Words.php'); please check updated answer. @KaniR

Answer (score 0):

Please try This

> $finalData = array();
>
> while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
>
> $finalData[] = array(
>             convertToWord($row['employeeTraveld']).'employeeTraveld' => $row['value']
>             );
>
> }
>
> print_r($finalData);
>
> function convertToWord($number) {
>
> $f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
>
> return $f->format($number);
>
> }